# Problem with emulator in ANdroid

Tags: android, emulation

invalid command-line parameter: ..\Documents\android-sdk-windows\tools/emulator-arm.exe.

Any idea how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Please provide some more context here....

Comment: Try \Documents\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator-arm.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem here is : you have to remove 1 extra space from the Eclipse path where you have declared your Android SDK from your local path. 
This u can verify by following steps : 
1. Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Select Android option from left column.
2. See the path : in my case its : D:\Andriod SDK\android-sdk-windows
3. If u observe, there is a space in Android & SDK. 
4. Close eclipse and go to the actual D location. 
5. Change the name of the Android SDK folder to AndroidSDK. (Just remove the space in betn). 
6. Restart the eclipse again and define the new path. 
BINGO... Your emulator will run without any problem.

Thanks
Saurabh M. Chande